# Проблема с svg и плагином fullpage

Tags: css3, html5, svg, fullpage

Вопрос в следующем:

Есть изображения комнаты. Я его разместил в блок. Блок должен растягиваться на всю ширину и высоту по экрану.

Мне нужно на этом изображения разместить svg выделения стола, стула и т.д.. Получается проблема заключается в том, что svg позиционируется отдельно от изображения. Не меняет разрешения и за этого выходит за пределы объекта. Как можно настроить svg так, чтобы при изменении размера окна, менялся и сам svg?

```css
.design-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 643px;
    position: relative;
}
.design-section img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.table-design-hover {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8%;
    width: 31%;
    left: 35%;
    height: 39%;
}
```

```html
<div class="design-section">
 <img src="img/bg-center.png" alt="">
  <div class="popup-design">
    <div class="table-design-hover">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/svg/hover-table.svg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Не меняет разрешения и за этого выходит за пределы объекта. Как можно
>   настроить svg так, чтобы при изменении размера окна, менялся и сам
>   svg?

Возможно у вас в заголовке файла **SVG** присутствуют  `viewport`,который определяется параметрами - `width="444.7"` и `height="670.9"` и `viewBox="0 0 444.7 670.9"`

При наличии обоих этих параметров масштабирование изображения SVG невозможно.
Картинка отображается в масштабе 1:1, то есть как она нарисована, так и отображается.

При попытке уменьшить размеры окна браузера, она сохраняет свои геометрические размеры и поэтому выходит за границы.

**Решение**

Убрать **viewport (`width`, `height)`** из заголовка файла SVG,
оставить только -  **viewBox="0 0 444.7 670.9"`**

Когда в файле SVG не указан `viewport`, браузер по умолчанию считает его равным 100% от размеров своего окна. Поэтому происходит масштабирование - картинка пытается его заполнить полностью при расширении или уменьшить размеры до размеров экрана.

**Возможен 2-ой вариант**

В css правилах присутствует : `position:absolute;` что выбивает SVG изображение из нормального потока.

Ниже пример масштабируемого SVG встроенного инлайн в HTML страничку.

```html
 <head>
  <title > shopping woman  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <style>
    #page{ margin: 1% 1%;padding:1% 3%;  width:100%; outline: 1px solid blue;}
    #container{width:80%; height:auto;padding:1% 3%;outline: 2px solid green;}
   p{width:100%;height:auto;margin: 1% 3%;font-size: 1.2em;}
   svg{margin: 1% 0%;outline: 1px solid crimson;}
  </style>
  <p>Это внешний "див" -- 100% от ширины страницы </p>
 <div id="page">  <p> "Это контейнер в котором находится SVG -- 80% от ширины страницы </p>
 <div id="container"> <p> "Это изображение SVG -- красная рамка -- его границы </p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    viewBox="0 0 444.7 670.9" version="1.1"  >
   <defs >
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient4202"><stop id="stop4204" stop-color="#c83737" offset="0"/><stop id="stop4206" stop-color="#f55" offset="1"/> </linearGradient> <linearGradient id="linearGradient4184"> <stop id="stop4186" stop-color="#f9c4a0" offset="0"/> <stop id="stop4188" stop-color="#e2894f" offset="1"/> </linearGradient> <linearGradient id="linearGradient3143"> <stop id="stop3145" stop-color="#f4eed7" offset="0"/><stop id="stop3147" stop-color="#d1c38b" offset="1"/></linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient3137" x1="118.6" xlink:href="#linearGradient3143" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" y1="450.8" gradientTransform="translate(-2.25 .5)" x2="118.2" y2="471.5"/> <linearGradient id="linearGradient3149" x1="135.9" xlink:href="#linearGradient3143" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" y1="425.7" gradientTransform="translate(-2.25 .5)" x2="146.7" y2="473.8"/> <linearGradient id="linearGradient4192" x1="239.1" xlink:href="#linearGradient4184" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="211.5" y1="516.6" y2="454"/> <linearGradient id="linearGradient4208" x1="148.9" xlink:href="#linearGradient4202" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="158.2" y1="248" y2="258.7"/> <linearGradient id="linearGradient4237" y2="201.9" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" y1="200.2" x2="211.6" x1="211.6"> <stop id="stop4233" stop-color="#c83737" offset="0"/><stop id="stop4235" stop-color="#782121" offset="1"/></linearGradient> <linearGradient id="linearGradient4249" x1="236.4" xlink:href="#linearGradient4202" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="190.1" y1="289.1" y2="359.1"/> <linearGradient id="linearGradient4283" x1="305.9" xlink:href="#linearGradient4184" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="306" y1="310.4" y2="323.1"/>
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient4285" x1="162.2" xlink:href="#linearGradient4184" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="178.9" y1="326.6" y2="335.1"/> <linearGradient id="linearGradient4423" y2="259.4" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" y1="283.1" x2="197.5" x1="190.1"><stop id="stop4419" stop-color="#f5a36c" offset="0"/><stop id="stop4421" stop-color="#f5a36c" stop-opacity="0" offset="1"/> </linearGradient><radialGradient id="radialGradient4466" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" cy="267.9" cx="117.6" gradientTransform="matrix(1.2119 1.6833 -1.6524 1.1897 455.67 -265.92)" r="191.5"><stop id="stop3933" stop-color="#fca" offset="0"/><stop id="stop3935" stop-color="#f60" offset="1"/></radialGradient> <filter id="filter4480" width="1.2" y="-0.1" x="-0.1" height="1.2" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"> <feGaussianBlur id="feGaussianBlur4482" stdDeviation="17.1"/> </filter>
    <filter id="filter4488" width="1.3" y="-0.6" x="-0.2" height="2.2" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feGaussianBlur id="feGaussianBlur4490" stdDeviation="16.8"/> </filter>
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient4514" x1="335.9" xlink:href="#linearGradient4184" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x2="332.7" y1="210.3" y2="234.3"/></defs> <g transform="translate(-11.334 -67.532)">
    <path opacity="0.5" d="m374.5 676.2a133.7 34.4 0 1 1-267.3 0 133.7 34.4 0 1 1 267.3 0z" transform="matrix(.88414 0 0 .88414 21.82 74.457)" filter="url(#filter4488)" fill="#803300"/> <rect  ry="82.2" height="489.7" filter="url(#filter4480)" width="362.9" y="108.5" x="52.3" fill="#520"/><rect  ry="82.2" height="489.7" width="362.9" stroke="#ffe6d5" y="102.5" x="46.3" stroke-width="20" fill="url(#radialGradient4466)"/><path  transform="translate(11.334 67.532)" fill="#fff" d="m201.8 63.8c-6.1 0.2-12.1 1.8-17.4 4.7-2.4 1.3-4.1 3.1-5.6 5-10-0.8-20.3-1.8-30.8-0.9-5 0.4-12 2.1-19.2 5-7.2 2.9-14.7 6.9-19.9 12.9-4.7 5.4-9.3 12.4-12.1 20.1-2.8 7.7-3.7 16.5 0.8 24.1 1.4 2.4 3.3 4.5 5.3 6.3-8.3 1-17.6 1.8-20.1 1.6-4.5-0.4-9.4-2.9-9.4-2.9a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-8.1 6.2s0.9 3.9 2.1 8.1c0.6 2.1 1.3 4.3 2 6.3 0.7 2 0.8 3.4 3.1 5.7 1.9 1.9 4.4 3.4 7.4 4.6s6.7 1.9 10.7 1.1c3.2-0.7 10.5-2.9 18.5-5.7 8-2.9 15.8-5.7 20.9-10.1 1.1-0.9 2.2-2 3.3-3.1 0.5 0.1 1 0.1 1.5 0.2-2.2 2.7-4.3 5.5-6 8.2-1.2 1.9-2.3 3.7-3.1 5.3-0.8 1.7-1.7 2.5-1.7 5.6 0 1.7 0.3 2.7 0.6 4.2 0.3 1.4 0.7 3 1.1 4.5 0.8 3 1.7 6.4 1.7 6.5 0 0.3 0 0.3 0.1 0.4a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.1 0.5 5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0 0 5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0 0.1c0.3 1 0.4 1.2 0.2 0.5a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.1 0.1c0.2 0.6 0.4 0.8 0.6 1.2h0c0.3 0.5 0.8 1.1 1.5 1.7a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.1 0.1c-1.5-1.1-1.6-1 0.3 0.2a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0 0c1.6 1.1 3.5 1.1 4.6 1 0 0 0 0 0.1 0 0.1 0 0.3-0.1 0.6-0.1a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.1 0c0.3-0.1 0.4-0.1 0.6-0.2 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.9 0.3 1.6 0.6 3.6 0.8 5.6 0.3 4 0.3 7.5 0.3 7.5a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 8.2 5l3.9-2.1c-0.9 2.4-1.6 5.5-0.8 9.2 0.6 2.9 1.8 5.5 2.7 7.5l-0.7 1a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-0.3 5.8l1.1 2.1c0 2.1 0 13 0 15.3 0 1.4 0.2 2 0.4 2.7-9.7 4.2-30.1 13-34.8 15.2-1.6 0.8-4.7 1.5-7.5 1.9-1.4 0.2-2.8 0.4-4 0.5-1.2 0.1-2 0.2-3.4 0.6-2.4 0.7-3.6 2.1-4.3 3.2-0.8 1.1-1.2 2.1-1.7 3-0.8 1.8-1.7 3.6-1.4 3.2-0.9 1.3-0.8 1.7-1 2.2-0.2 0.5-0.3 1-0.4 1.5-0.2 1.1-0.5 2.4-0.7 3.9-0.5 3-1 6.7-1.6 10.5-0.5 3.7-1 7.5-1.4 10.3-0.2 1.4-0.3 2.7-0.5 3.6-0.1 0.9-0.3 1.8-0.2 1.4-0.5 2.5 0.2 3.5 0.6 4.5 0.3 0.8 0.7 1.3 1 1.9-1 1.3-1.7 2.7-2.2 4.4-1.7 6-1.6 13.4-1.3 19.8 0.3 5.9 0.7 10.1 0.8 10.8-0.2 0.5-0.5 0.9-0.7 1.4-0.7 2.1-1.3 4.2-1.7 5.9-0.4 1.8-0.7 2.9-0.7 4.7 0 1.9 0.5 2.7 0.8 3.6 0.2 0.4 0.4 0.8 0.6 1.2 0 1.3 0 2.2 0.1 4.2a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0 0.6 5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0 0.1c0 2.5 0.1 4.9 0.2 6.3 0.1 2.4 0.6 5 1.3 7.4 0.3 1.2 0.7 2.3 1.1 3.4 0.4 1.1 0 2 2.9 4 1.5 1 3.3 2 6.3 3.3s6.2 2.7 10.3 2.7c1.5 0 5 0.4 8.3 0.4 1.7 0 3.4 0 5.2-0.3 1.1-0.2 2.3-0.6 3.5-1.2 0.4-0.1 1-0.2 1.3-0.3 1.1-0.6 1.6-1.1 2.1-1.5 1-0.9 1.8-1.9 2.6-3 1.6-2.2 3-4 3.9-6.6 0.8-2 0.5-2.7 0.5-3.7 0-0.9-0.1-1.9-0.3-2.9-0.3-2-0.7-4.2-1.2-6.5s-0.9-4.4-1.2-6.2c-0.3-1.7-0.2-3.6-0.4-2.3 0.3-2.3 0-4-0.3-5.8-0.3-1.6-0.6-3-0.8-4l0-0.1-0.4-2.8c0-6.8 0.5-14.5-2.1-20.8-1.7-4.3-3.9-9.5-7.3-14.1 0.2-1.1 0.5-2 0.7-3.2 0.3-2.2 0.8-4.1 0.1-6.9-0.4-1.6-1.2-5.5-2.2-9.2-0.5-1.8-1.1-3.6-1.7-5.2-0.3-0.8-0.6-1.5-1.1-2.3-0.3-0.5-0.8-1.3-1.7-2-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6 0.1 0 0.1-0.1 0.2-0.1 1.1-0.6 2.3-1.1 2.3-1.1a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.1 0s3-1.2 6.5-2.5 8-2.7 9.4-2.9c2.8-0.5 7.8-1.8 13.9-3.4 4.1-1.1 8-2.2 11.8-3.2 1 5.4 3 9.1 2 13.6-1.6 7.6-4 20.3-3.2 28.8 0.3 3.8 1.4 11.2 2.4 18.6 0.5 3.7 1 7.3 1.3 10.2 0.4 2.9 0.6 5.4 0.6 5.8 0 1.7-0.3 5-0.8 7.9-0.3 1.4-0.6 2.7-0.9 3.6-0.1 0.4-0.3 0.8-0.4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0-1.2 1.2-3.9 3.1-3.9 3.1a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 2.7 10.3s9.6 0.6 16.2 0.9c4.2 10.6 10.3 25.7 14.7 35.3-2.3 18.5-4.7 39.2-4.9 41.4-0.3 2.9 0.1 5.4 0.5 8.1s0.6 4.5 1 6.2c-0.4-1.4-0.1-0.9-0.1-0.7 0 0.3 0 0.7-0.1 1.3-0.1 1.2-0.2 2.8-0.4 4.7-0.3 3.6-0.6 7.9-0.4 11.5 0.3 4.9 1.3 10.1 2.2 14.8 0.9 4.7 1.7 9 1.7 10.6 0 3.2 0.4 13.1 0.6 23 0.1 4.9 0.1 9.7 0.1 13.5 0 1.9 0 3.4-0.1 4.6s-0.5 2.3 0 0.9c-0.2 0.7-0.5 1.8-0.8 2.6a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-2.7 4.3c-0.3 4.2 0.1 6.7 0.3 8.3a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 2.6 4c0.2 0.6 0.4 1.3 0.6 1.8 0.2 0.8 0.4 1.4 0.4 1.8 0 0.1 0 0.3 0 0.4 0 0.3 0 0.6 0 0.9 0 0.2 0 0.6 0 0.9-0.6 1.1-1.2 2.4-1.4 3.7-0.5 3 0 5.3 0.4 7.3 0.3 1.1 0.4 1.4 0.6 2-0.2 3.6-0.6 6.5-0.8 7.9-1.2 1.4-2.8 3.8-3.2 7.9-0.3 2.9-1.4 9.2 2.8 14.8 1.2 1.6 3 4.3 5.6 6.6 1.3 1.2 2.9 2.4 5.2 2.9 2.3 0.6 5.5 0 7.6-1.6 2.3-1.8 5-4.4 7.5-6.9 1.2-1.3 2.4-2.5 3.3-3.5 0.9-1 1.4-1.4 2.3-2.8 1.2-1.9 1.1-2.8 1.2-3.9 0.1-1.1 0.2-2.2 0.2-3.2 0-2.2-0.1-4-0.7-6.1-0.5-1.9-1-3-1.4-3.8-0.2-1.1-0.4-2.1-0.7-3.2 0.2 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.6 0.3 1 0.4 2 0.8 2.9 1 0.9 0.3 1.3 0.5 3.1 0.5 0.4 0 5.2 0 9.9-0.1 2.4-0.1 4.7-0.2 6.8-0.3 1-0.1 1.9-0.1 2.8-0.3 0.9-0.1 1.4 0.1 3.4-1.1 0.1-0.1 0.2-0.2 0.3-0.3a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 4.4 2.2h2.2a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 5.6-5.3s0.4-6.9 0.8-13.9c0.2-3.5 0.5-7 0.7-9.7 0.1-1.4 0.2-2.5 0.3-3.3 0-0.2 0.1-0.4 0.1-0.5 0.4-0.7 1.8-3.4 1.8-7.3 0-3.3-1.2-5.6-2.4-7.8-1.2-2.2-2.4-4-4.7-5.7 1.3 0.9 0.6 0.6 0.3-0.1-0.3-0.7-0.7-1.9-1-3s-0.6-2.2-0.7-2.9c0-0.2 0-0.2-0.1-0.3a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-2.5-5c-0.1-1.5-0.2-3.2-0.4-5.3-0.3-4.4-0.8-9.8-1.2-15.2-0.4-5.4-0.8-10.8-1.1-15.2-0.3-4.4-0.2-8.3-0.2-8.2 0.8-5.9 4.5-26.9-8.3-40.4-5-5.2-7.4-8.4-8.4-10.4-1-2-1.1-3.2-1.1-6.4 0-5.4-1.4-17.4-3-28.7 3.9-8.9 8.1-19.1 11.7-27.9 2.1-0.3 4.3-0.6 5.8-1.1 3.6-1.1 6.7-3.2 10.1-5.5 0.8-0.5 1.6-1.1 2.3-1.6a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0 0c3.3-2.3 5.7-4.2 6.9-5.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.7-0.5 1.1-0.8 1.1-0.8a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 1.3-7.4s-1.5-2.4-3.3-5.5c-0.9-1.6-1.9-3.2-2.7-4.6-0.8-1.5-1.5-2.9-1.8-3.8-0.7-1.8-2.7-6.7-5.1-12.5-2.8-6.7-6.2-14.5-9.2-20.4 0 0 0 0 0-0.1 0 0 0-0.1 0-0.1a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-0.1-0.1 5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0 0c-1.3-2.6-2.5-4.8-3.7-6.5-1.6-2.4-4-5.1-6.9-8.3v0c0 0 0 0 0 0a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-0.1-0.1 5.6 5.6 0 0 0-0.1-0.1c-2.9-3.1-6.1-6.6-9.3-9.8-3.3-3.3-6.5-6.4-9-8.8-1.3-1.2-2.4-2.2-3.3-3-0.8-0.7-1.2-1.1-2.2-1.7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0-0.4-0.5-1.3-2.5-1.7-3.7 0.2-1.2 0.6-3.9 1.4-8.1 0.2-1.2 0.5-2.5 0.8-3.7 0.2-1.2 0.5-2.3 0.7-3.4 0.5-2.1 1.3-4.2 0.8-3.2 1.2-2.4 2.3-5.7 3.4-9.1 0.5-1.6 0.6-1.9 1-3.1a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 3.6-7.2l0.8-1a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 1.1-5s-0.3-1.1-0.7-2.4l3.8-8.4c3 4.4 6.3 9.4 7.7 11.9 2.1 4.1 5.5 8.2 8.7 12.2 3.2 3.9 6.2 8.2 6.4 8.5 2 4.2 5.7 10.1 12.8 12.9 0.6 0.3 1.2 0.4 1.6 0.5a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0 0c0.8 0.2 1.7 0.4 2.7 0.5 0.5 0 0.8 0.1 0.9 0.1 0.9 0 1.8 0 2.8-0.2 2.6-0.4 11.5-1.8 19.6-3-0.4 8.2-0.4 14.1-0.2 17.9l-1.1 0.3a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-4 6.2s1 7.1 1.8 15.2c0.9 8.1 1.4 17.8 1.1 20.5-1.8 14.7-1.4 35.8 2 51a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 4.7 4.3l12.2 1.7a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 3.8-0.8l14-9.1 7.9 1.2a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 4-0.9s5.4-3.7 11-7.5c2.8-1.9 5.6-3.8 7.8-5.2 1.1-0.7 2-1.3 2.7-1.7 0.3-0.2 0.6-0.4 0.8-0.5s0.5-0.2-0.3 0.1c2.2-0.9 3.4-2.3 4.3-3.8 0.9-1.5 1.6-3.3 1.1-5.9-0.2-1-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.7-0.2-0.7-0.5-1.5-0.8-2.6-0.6-2.1-1.5-4.8-2.3-7.8-1.7-6-3.6-13.1-4.4-17.7-1.4-8.4-1.9-28-1.9-28a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-6.4-5.4l-3.3 0.5c-3.7-10.3-9.4-19.6-14.4-28.9 0.5-0.6 1.1-1.1 1.6-1.7 1.8-2 3.3-4 4.1-5 0.1-0.1 1.9-1.8 3.6-3s3.2-2.2 3.9-2.7c4.2-2.8 6.4-7.9 4.3-12.4 0.6-0.5 1.1-1 2.4-2.2 0.9-0.8 1.9-1.7 2.7-2.5 0.8-0.8 1.5-1.4 2.2-2.2 2-2.2 3.2-4.5 2.9-7.7-0.2-1.6-0.9-3.9-3.4-5.2-0.6-0.3-1.2-0.5-1.8-0.6 0-0.1 0.1-0.3 0.2-0.4 0.2-0.5 0.3-1.1 0.5-1.7 0 0 0-0.1 0-0.1 0.3-1.1 0.4-1.9 0.4-3.2h0c0-0.3 0-0.5 0-0.7 0-1.1-0.1-2.3-0.6-3.5-0.6-1.5-1.9-3.3-4.1-4.1-0.7-0.2-1.4-0.3-2.1-0.2-0.6-0.7-1.5-1.3-2.8-1.7-1.2-0.4-3-0.4-4.5 0.2-0.5 0.2-0.8 0.5-1.2 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0-1.5-0.5-3.8-0.1-5 0.7s-1.8 1.8-2.2 2.5a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-0.3 0.8s-1 3-2.1 6.2c-0.6 1.6-1.2 3.2-1.7 4.6-0.5 1.3-1.1 2.6-0.9 2.2-1.1 1.9-2.6 5.3-4.5 9.4-0.9 2-1.9 4.1-2.6 5.8-0.7 1.7-1.2 2.6-1.7 4.4 0.3-1.3-0.2 0.3-1 1.6-0.5 0.9-1.3 1.9-1.9 2.9-0.6 0.3-1.4 1.1-2.3 1.8-0.8 0.3-1.6 0.7-2.4 1.4-0.1 0.1-0.1 0.2-0.2 0.3-0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2 0-0.8-0.8-1.7-1.9-5.2-1.5-0.8 0.1-1.8 0.4-2.7 0.8-1.5 0.2-3.4 0.8-5.1 2.2-1.9 0.2-3.8 0.4-5.3 0.5-2.1 0.2-3.9 0.2-3.9 0.2-2.6-0.2-11.8-1.6-14.9-2.1-0.9-1.5-2.1-3.4-4.4-7.2-3-4.9-6.5-10.8-6.6-11.1-1.1-2.3-3.5-6.1-6-10.2-2.3-3.8-4.3-6.9-4.5-7.3-0.2-0.4-1.7-4-3.7-8.7-2.1-4.9-4.4-10.1-6.4-13.4-2.7-4.4-7-6.3-10.7-7.3s-6.7-1.4-9.5-1.1c0.2 0-1.8-0.1-3.7-0.4-1.4-0.2-2.6-0.7-3.8-1.1-0.8-1.1-1.7-1.8-2.7-2.5 0.5-0.3 1.6-1.1 2.8-1.7 1.9-1 4.4-2.2 6.9-3.5s5.1-2.5 7.3-3.7c1.5-0.8 2.7-1.4 3.9-2.2 8.9-1 17.5-2.7 25-5.6 18.4-7.2 40.8-18.7 47.9-39.8 2.1-6.2 4.2-15 3.6-23.5-0.3-4.2-1.4-8.6-4.1-12.2-2.7-3.7-7.3-6.2-12.6-6.7-7.6-0.7-19.5 0.5-32.6 2-11.9 1.4-24 3-33.4 4.3-1.4-1.7-3-3.3-5.3-4.4-5.5-2.7-11.7-3.7-17.7-3.5zm-41.4 92.5c0.2 1 0.6 2 1 3 1.8 4 6.3 7.4 11.4 7.3 3.5-0.1 6.8-0.5 9.2-0.4 0.4 0 0.5 0.1 0.8 0.1-0.9 0.7-1.8 1.5-2.8 2.4-1.6-0.2-4.2-0.6-7.8 0.4-4.7 1.3-6.3 4.1-8.4 7.2-2.1 3.1-3.9 6.5-4.7 10.3-0.3 1.5-0.7 4.1-1 6.3-0.7-3.5-1.5-7.4-3.7-10.9-2.2-3.5-5.3-5.9-8-8-0.5-0.4-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.6 0.6-1.1 0.6-1.3 1.4-2.7 2.1-3.6 5.2-7.8 6.9-9.1 1.9-1.5 4.2-3.3 6.5-5.1zm-45 136.5c0.4 0.2 0.7 0.4 0.8 0.6-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.6 0 0 0 0 0 0zm-13.7 44.7a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.8 0.7l3.9 2.8a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 1.2 0.6l8.1 3.1c0.1 0.7 0.1 0.6 0.2 1.6 0 0.2 0 0.5 0 0.7-6.3-0.9-11.2-1.2-14-1.4-0.1-1-0.1-0.9-0.1-2-0.1-2.2 0-3.8 0-6zm-1.4 18.5c0.1 0 0 0.1-0.3 0.3 0.1-0.1 0.1-0.2 0.2-0.2a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.1-0.1zm112.8 102.5c0.3 0.4 0.5 0.9 0.8 1.3 1 1.4 1.9 2.7 3.3 3.8 0.3 0.3 0.8 0.5 1.2 0.8 1.3 3.2 10.5 25.4 12.3 38.9 1.5 10.8 2.8 26.5 3.4 36.8a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-1.2 3.3l-0.1 6.6a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.7 2.8c-0.1 0.4-0.2 0.7-0.4 1.2a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-1.4 2l-2.1 5.2a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.3 4.9 5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0 0c-0.3 1.5-0.7 3.1-0.7 4.6-0.1 3.5 0.1 6.9 0.2 9.5 0 0.3-0.1 0.4-0.1 0.7 0 0-4.2 3.2-6.8 5.1-0.9 0.7-1.6 1.1-2.6 1.6-1 0.6-2.5 1.5-3.7 3-0.2 0.3-0.3 0.8-0.5 1.1-0.3-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.7-1.5-0.1-0.9-0.1-2.2-0.6-4-0.3-1.2-0.7-2.5-1.6-4-0.5-0.9-1.4-1.9-2.4-2.8-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7 0-0.2 0-0.3-0.1-0.4 0-0.2 0.2-1.8 0.3-2.7a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.6-0.9c2.4-4.7 0.9-8.6 0.8-10.1a5.6 5.6 0 0 0-1-2.8c-0.4-7.7 0.9-35.8 1.1-38.9 0 0.1 0.4-2.3 0.9-5 0.6-2.7 1.3-6.2 2-10 1.4-7.6 2.8-16.3 2.3-23.7-0.3-4.6-2-9.1-3.4-13-0.7-1.9-1.3-3.7-1.7-4.9-0.2-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.2-1.5 0.1-0.4 0.1-0.4 0.2-1.2 0.3-1.3 0.6-3 1.1-4.9zm42.9 87.4c-0.1 0.2-0.2 0.3-0.3 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0a5.6 5.6 0 0 0 0.4-0.5z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="layer2" transform="translate(-11.334 -67.532)">
    <path  fill="url(#linearGradient3137)" d="m103.6 433.2s0.2 14 0.3 17.4c0.2 3.5 1.7 9.7 2.8 10.4 1 0.7 9 5 13.5 5s14 1.6 15.5-1.4c1.6-2.9-3.3-28.3-3.3-28.3zM136.2 423.5l-7.8 2.1 1.7 12.6 7.8-3.9"/>
    <path id="path3129" fill="#504416" d="m136.2 423.5-7.8 2.1 1.7 12.6 7.8-3.9z"/>
    <path id="path3125" fill="url(#linearGradient3149)" d="m137.6 427.5s1.7 6.6 1.4 9.3c-0.3 2.8 3.8 18 2.9 20.2-0.9 2.2-5.5 9-6.4 8.1-0.9-0.9-0.2-8.6-0.2-9.7s-4-20-4-20z"/>
    <path id="path3151" fill="#decd87" d="m103.6 433.2s0.1 5.7 0.2 10.7c1.7 2.5 5.7 5 7.4 5.7 3.3 1.4 17.1-2.7 19.3-3.8 1-0.5 2.1-1.8 3-3.1-0.6-3.7-1.2-6.4-1.2-6.4z"/>
    <path id="path3123" fill="#f4eed7" d="m109.6 418.3c-4.3 1.2-7.4 14.2-7.4 16.6 0 2.4 6.4 11.4 8.8 11.7 2.4 0.3 18.6-4.5 20.4-7.2 1.7-2.8 1.7-13.1 3.1-14.2 1.4-1 1.9 4.7 1.9 4.7l1.6-0.7-0.9-6c-0.7-3.3-27.4-4.8-27.4-4.8z"/>
    <path id="path3156" transform="matrix(.99589 .090591 -.068041 .74799 26.561 101.75)" fill="#6c5353" d="m121 439.2c0 2.5-2 4.5-4.5 4.5-2.5 0-4.5-2-4.5-4.5 0-2.5 2-4.5 4.5-4.5 2.5 0 4.5 2 4.5 4.5z"/>
    <path id="path3158" fill="#e9ddaf" d="m135 442.5s-0.9-3.8-1.2-8.7c-0.5-9.1-0.7-22.3-1.7-25.5-1.6-4.8-7.2-15.6-14.5-16.6-4-0.5-9.6 3-10.1 6.8-0.8 6.2 0.5 20.7 0.5 20.7-0.8 0.3-2.7 3.7-2.7 3.7s-2.3-20 0.3-29.2c1.4-5.1 8.8-8.6 14.1-7.6 8.3 1.6 12.9 11.8 16.1 19.7 2.1 5.3 1.6 17.9 1.7 25.1 0.1 7.3 0.9 9.2 0.9 9.2z"/>
    <path  fill="#f55" d="m143.6 200.2s-8 9.7-16.5 11.9c-8.5 2.2-27.3 4.1-33.4 3.6-6.1-0.6-11.6-3.6-11.6-3.6s3.6 15.1 5.8 17.3c2.2 2.2 8 5.2 13 4.1 5-1.1 30.3-8.8 36.9-14.6 6.6-5.8 14.6-15.4 14.6-15.4l-8.8-3.3zm22.6 9.1c-1.1 0.3-7.7 5.5-13.2 11.6-5.5 6.1-11.9 16-11.9 18.5 0 2.5 2.9 11.9 3.3 14.3 0.6 3.6 3.8-2.5 7.2 1.4s3 19 3 19l10.5-5.5s-1.2-11.5-4.2-16.2c-2.6-4.3-11.3-9.9-11.3-9.9s6.1-13.3 12.1-17.9c6.1-4.7 17.1-13.5 17.1-13.5l-12.7-1.7z"/>
    <path  fill="#f4eed7" d="m187.1 157.4s5.4-13.3 11.2-16.5c8.8-4.8 21-5.4 30-1 5.1 2.5 10 13.7 10 13.7z"/>
    <path  fill="#decd87" d="m159.8 145.7c-8.3 0.7-26.8 6.2-35.3 16-8.5 9.9-17.3 26.5-10.7 37.8 11.4 19.6 53.5 16 66.1 16s58.9 4.9 85.4-5.5c17.9-7 38.5-18.2 44.6-36.4 3.9-11.3 7.7-33.6-8.3-35s-68.1 7.2-79.1 8c-20.8 3.4-42.2-2.6-62.8-0.8z"/>
    <path  fill="#800000" d="m194.1 172.1s-18.9 8.6-22.2 10.1c-3.3 1.6-12.7 5.1-12.3 10.9 0.4 5.8 17.5 11.7 18.9 12.3 1.4 0.6 4.5 0.8 4.5 0.8s-2.9 1.2-5.3 8 0 14.4 6.2 14.2c6.2-0.2 13.6-1.6 16.4 1.8 2.7 3.3 6.4 9 6.4 9s8.4-9.2 10.7-11.5c2.3-2.3 22.6-11.1 23.2-12.7 0.6-1.6-3.7-2.7-4.5-3.1-0.8-0.4-0.4-1.8 4.1-2.9 4.5-1.2 5.7-5.1 4.3-5.5-1.4-0.4-2.1-1.9-1.8-3.5 0.4-1.6-0.2-2.9-1.4-3.3-1.2-0.4 4.9-3.5 7.2-5.3s2.5-5.3-0.2-5.8c-2.7-0.6-3.9-1.2-3.5-3.5 0.4-2.3 4.9-3.5 4.7-4.5-0.2-1-55.6-5.5-55.6-5.5z"/>
    <path  fill="#f5a36c" d="m188.9 181.7c-0.2 0-0.5 0.1-0.7 0.2-1.9 1.2 0.5 14.9 2.9 15.3 1.8 0.3 3.3-4.4 3.3-4.4l-2-8.2s-1.7-3-3.4-2.9zm44.9 0.4c-1.7 0-3.4 2.9-3.4 2.9l-2 8.2s1.5 4.6 3.3 4.4c2.4-0.4 4.8-14.1 2.9-15.3-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.7-0.2z"/>
    <path fill="url(#linearGradient4192)" d="m188.2 437s16.5 42.2 21.8 52.1c5.2 9.9 16.2 25.7 16.5 27.6 0.8 4.7 5.5 11.9 7.4 11 0 0 11.3 26.2 13.5 42.4 2.2 16.3 4.4 44.1 3.9 47.7-0.6 3.6-5 14.1-5.2 20.7-0.3 6.6 1.1 13.8-1.1 16.3-2.2 2.5-5.2 4.7-5.2 4.7l12.4 3.3s3.3-1.7 3.6-4.1c0.3-2.5-1.1-17.4 2.8-19.6 3.9-2.2 7.7-2.2 9.9-3.3s3.9-6.6-0.3-11c-4.1-4.4-8.5-10.5-8-15.2 0.6-4.7-3.6-42.7-2.8-48.5 0.8-5.8 3.3-25.1-6.9-35.8s-11-13.8-11-20.7c0-6.9-3.6-36.4-5.8-44.9-2.2-8.5-9.9-34.2-9.9-34.2z"/>
    <path  fill="#f9c4a0" d="m205.6 206.6s-2.5 25.1-3.6 27.8c-1.1 2.8-5.5 6.3-7.4 7.2-1.9 0.8-6.6-0.6-9.6 0.3s-8 8-9.1 13.2c-1.1 5.2-3 21.5-3 21.5l11.9 19 41.1 3.3 12.4-27.8s10.5 14.3 13.8 20.7c3.3 6.3 13.2 16.8 15.2 20.9 1.9 4.1 7.7 11.9 14.9 10.7 7.2-1.1 48.2-7.4 51.3-7.4 3 0 8-6.6 9.9-9.1 1.9-2.5 7.8-6.2 8.8-6.9 2.7-1.8 3.1-4.2 2.4-5.5-0.4-0.7-3.5 0.6-3.5 0.6l3.9-6.1s6.4-5.6 7.7-7.2c2.5-2.8 1.5-5 0.4-4l-9.9 7.7s5.3-12.2 6.2-15.5c2.1-6.8-1-7.5-1.8-5 0 0-0.9 1.7-1.7 3.3 0.9-5.1-1.7-7.7-2.5-6.2l-5.9 15.7s2.1-7.5 2.4-10.2c0.3-2.8-1-6-1.9-4.3 0 0-4 12-5.1 13.9-1.1 1.9-7.7 16-8.3 18.2-0.6 2.2-7.4 11.6-7.4 11.6s-24.5 3-28.7 2.8c-4.1-0.3-17.9-2.5-17.9-2.5s-11.3-18.2-12.7-20.9c-1.4-2.8-10.5-17.4-10.5-17.4s-6.9-16.8-9.9-21.8c-3-5-12.1-6.1-14.9-5.8-2.8 0.3-11.8-1.4-14.6-3.9-2.8-2.5-4.1-2.5-3-9.1 1.1-6.6 5-20.4 5-20.4z"/>
    <path  fill="#ce7335" d="m205.6 206.6s-0.4 3.8-0.9 8.3c1 1.4 3.1 2.9 5 3.2 2.7 0.4 5-0.6 7.8-2.3 1.1-4.3 2.1-7.8 2.1-7.8z"/>
    <path  fill="#f9c4a0" d="m192.4 168.6s-1.1 12.1-1.5 13.7c-1.1 4.6 0.3 13.8 1 15.7 2 5.5 10.2 10.5 13 13.8 2 2.4 10.6 3.6 13.9-0.2 2.7-3.1 10.6-8.6 11.9-13.2 1-3.6 1.7-17.7 0.9-21.9-0.8-4.1-0.7-10.3-0.7-10.3-11.2-6.2-23-10-38.4 2.3z"/>
    <path  fill="url(#linearGradient4285)" d="m174.7 321.8s-38.3 16.5-43.5 19c-5.2 2.5-13.8 2.8-15.7 3.3-1.9 0.6-3.1 5.4-4.3 7.2-1.2 1.7-4.5 29.7-4.8 31.3-0.3 1.6 4 7 4 7l1.3 4.5 4 2.8 1.4 4.2 3.9 2.8 8.1 3.2s1.6-1.2 0-4.6c-1.3-2.9-1.5-2.8-2.3-4l-2.6-3.8c-2.4-5.4-0.7-4.9 0-6l3.2 2.9c0.8-3.1 1.9-8.3 1.4-10.5-0.7-3.2-3.4-15.3-5-15.9-1.6-0.6-2.5-5.6-2.2-7.5 0.4-1.9 6.2-4.1 6.2-4.1s12.1-4.9 17.1-5.7c5-0.8 38.4-10.2 38.4-10.2z"/>
    <path  fill="#f9c4a0" d="m221.3 431.5s-7.4 17.6-9.6 27.8-8.5 65.6-8.8 68.3c-0.3 2.8 1.1 11.3 1.4 12.4 0.3 1.1-1.1 11.9-0.8 17.9 0.4 8.6 3.9 20.1 3.9 25.6 0 5.5 1.4 40.8 0.3 43.8-1.1 3-2.8 8.3-1.9 10.7 0.8 2.5 3 9.4 2.8 10.5-0.3 1.1 0.2 20-1.7 25.9-2.1 6.7-0.2 11.9-0.2 11.9s21.1-1.7 20.8-2.8c-0.3-1.1 0-11.3-2.8-16.5-2.8-5.2-8.8-18.5-8.8-20.9 0-2.5 1.4-7.2 0.8-15.4-0.6-8.3 0.8-36.9 1.1-40.8 0.3-3.9 6.1-25.3 5.2-38-0.5-6.8-5.8-17.4-5.5-19.6 0.3-2.2 7.2-34.4 12.7-44.1 5.5-9.6 25.6-59.8 25.6-59.8z"/>
    <path  fill="url(#linearGradient4423)" d="m182.9 286.7s5.4-3.8 7.4-9.2c2.3-6.2 2.6-14.2 2-16.2-0.4-1.2 3.1 1.5 4.9 1.5s8.4-3.2 5.3-1.5c-1.7 0.9-10.9 14.3-9.1 21.7 1.6 6.6 5.5 7.6 5.5 7.6l-12.2 2.6z"/>
    <path  fill="#f55" d="m201.6 235.2s-5 2.9-9.9 7.9c-0.9 0.9-15.8 20.1-15.8 20.1s-7 11-8 12.5c-1 1.5-3 5.5-2.2 9.2 0.8 3.7 3.7 9.1 3.7 9.1l-2.5 3.7 1.8 3.3s0 14.3 0 16.8c0 2.5 7.4 21.2 8 25.9 0.6 4.7 3.9 10.3 2.3 17.5-1.6 7.2-3.7 20.5-3.1 27.1 0.6 6.6 4.3 30.6 4.3 35.1 0 4.5-1.4 13.8-3.3 16-1.9 2.1-5.3 4.3-5.3 4.3s17.7 1.2 21.2 1.2c3.5 0 21.4 4.1 25.7 2.5 4.3-1.6 33.7-4.3 39.4-6 5.7-1.8 18.7-12.1 18.7-12.1s-6.4-9.9-8.4-14.8c-1.9-4.9-12.5-31.4-17.5-38.8-5.1-7.4-27.1-29.2-29.4-30.4-2.3-1.2-4.5-7.6-4.5-7.6s3.1-18.9 4.5-21.6c1.4-2.7 5.1-14.6 5.1-14.6l2.5-0.4-1.6-2.3 3.3-4.1s-4.3-17.1-8-22.8c-3.7-5.7-6-9.7-6-9.7l4-22.3c-0.9-4.8-5.4-4.6-5.4-4.6l2.7 3.1-3.7 24.9s-11.1 8.2-14.2 12.7c-3.1 4.5-11.7 12.7-11.7 12.7l-11.1-25.3s18.1-22.3 19.4-23c2.4-1.3 4.9-5.1 4.9-5.1z"/>
    <path  fill="#800000" d="m203.7 161.7c0.8 2.5-6.5 9.6-8 12.4-1.6 2.7-3.7 3.9-4.4 5 0.1 1.7-0.3 3.4-0.5 4.3-0.9-0.9-1.3-2-1.9-1.7-2.7 1.2-4.4 3.9-7.2 4.1-2.6 0.2-5.4-2-7.4-2.5-1.9-0.6-8.2-5.3-4.3-9.5s15.6-4.9 19.1-5.8c3.5-1 2.6-1.6 3.9-2.3 6.2-3.3 10.8-3.8 10.8-3.8z"/>
    <path  fill="#f5a36c" d="m215.6 186.5s-0.8-2.5-0.8-4.2c0-1.6 2.1-3.7 2.1-3.7l7.1-2.3 3.7 1.5c2 2.4 0.3 6.3-1.3 7.6l-9 0.3z"/>
    <path id="path3017" fill="#800000" d="m213 163.3c1.8 1.5 3.1 4.9 5.3 6.4s10.9 5.9 12.1 6.9c1.2 1 1.6 8 1.2 11.3-0.4 3.3 3.6 5.4 3.6 5.4s-1.7-1.5-2-4.3c-0.4-3.4 0.9-6.4 1.7-7 2.1-1.5 3 0.7 6.3 0.5 3.9-0.2 6.5-2.4 8.2-3.4 3.1-1.8 0.5-9.5-3.4-11-3.9-1.6-14-2.3-15.6-3.9s-2.3-4.7-4.5-5.7c-6.2-2.6-17.1 0.8-19.9 2.3-1.2 0.6 4.7 0.5 7 2.4z"/>
    <path  fill="#f5a36c" d="m210.2 181.3c0.2 2.1-1.6 4.9-1.6 4.9l-2.5-2s-9.1 0-9.5-0.2c-3.2 0.6-3.3-4.8-1.2-5.5l6-2.2 6.6 2.2s2.1 0.6 2.3 2.7z"/>
    <path  fill="#800000" d="m195.2 178.7s5.6-3.2 6.2-3c0.6 0.1 8.6 2.3 8.6 2.3s-2.1 1.5-2.7 1.3c-0.6-0.1-5.9-2.5-7.1-2.5s-5 1.8-5 1.8z"/>
    <path fill="#800000" d="m214.6 178.4 3 1.2s5.5-2.5 6.4-2.5c0.9 0 5.6 1.8 5.6 1.8s-5.2-3.3-5.9-3.3c-0.7 0-9 2.8-9 2.8z"/>
    <path  d="m197.7 183.5s3.1-2.9 5.8-2.8c2.9 0.1 5.8 5.5 5.8 5.5l-1.5 0.1-0.6-0.8s-3.6 0.9-5.4 0.9c-1.1 0-1.9 0.1-3.3-0.7-1.3-0.9-3.6-2-3.6-2z"/>
    <path  d="m215.1 186.1s1.9-4.4 3.5-4.9c1.6-0.4 3.6 0.4 5 1.6 1 0.9 2.1 2.3 2.1 2.3l2.1-1s-1.5 1.7-2 1.9c-0.5 0.1-2.2 0.2-3.3 0.3-0.7 0.1-1.4 0.3-2.1 0.4-1.4 0.1-4.2 0-4.2 0l-0.7 0.7z"/>
    <path  fill="#fff" d="m206 183.2c0 0.4-0.4 0.8-0.8 0.8-0.4 0-0.8-0.4-0.8-0.8 0-0.4 0.4-0.8 0.8-0.8 0.4 0 0.8 0.4 0.8 0.8z"/>
    <path  transform="translate(16.873 .22202)" fill="#fff" d="m206 183.2c0 0.4-0.4 0.8-0.8 0.8-0.4 0-0.8-0.4-0.8-0.8 0-0.4 0.4-0.8 0.8-0.8 0.4 0 0.8 0.4 0.8 0.8z"/>
    <path  fill="#ce7335" d="m207.3 195.7 2.7-1.2c1.2 1.2 2.2 0.7 3.3 0.2l2.3 1s-1.6 0.1-2.3 0.7c-0.8 0.6-2.8 0.5-3.5-0.1-0.7-0.6-2.5-0.6-2.5-0.6z"/>
    <path  fill="#f5a36c" d="m205.9 203.1s1.9 1.9 3.1 2c1.2 0.2 4.7 0.3 5.1 0.1 0.5-0.2 2.4-2.3 2.4-2.3s-2 3.3-2.3 3.6c-0.3 0.3-5.2 0.1-5.5 0.1-0.3 0-2.9-3.5-2.9-3.5z"/>
    <path  fill="#c83737" d="m203.5 199.8s2.7 4.5 4.7 5.2c2 0.7 5 0.7 6 0.3 2.1-0.9 5-5.2 5-5.2l-6.6 0.9z"/>
    <path  fill="#ce7335" d="m202.8 198.3-1.5 1.9 1.9-0.6zm17.5 0.4-0.5 1.1 1.7 1.1z"/>
    <path  fill="url(#linearGradient4237)" d="m211.6 199.6c-1.7-0.1-1.5-1-2.7-0.9-0.8 0.1-1.6 1.5-2 1.6-0.4 0.1-4.6-1-4.6-1s3.1 1.7 4.8 2c2.4 0.5 4.9 0.7 7.3 0.4 2.1-0.3 3.9-0.8 6.1-2.1 0 0-3.9 0.8-4.6 0.7-0.7-0.1-1.1-1.5-1.9-1.5-1 0.1-1.4 0.8-2.4 0.8z"/>
    <path  fill="#a00" d="m244 652.9s5.3 5.2 6.9 5.1c1.6-0.1 6-19 6-19l-10.7-8.2 2.1-5.2s10.7 9.1 11.2 9.1c0.5 0 2.7-0.2 3.1-0.2 0.4 0 4.2-5.8 3.9-8-0.3-2.3-4.4-10.4-4.4-10.4-4.7 1.5-8.1 1.2-12.3 1.5l0.1-6.6c3.8 0.9 8.3 0.3 12.9-0.7-0.4 0.1 1.5 9.6 3.8 11.2 1.9 1.4 4.8 6.1 4.8 9s-1.2 4.4-1.7 5.7-2.1 28.8-2.1 28.8h-2.2s0.2-23.1 0-24.3c-0.2-1.2-2.8-1.7-3.7-0.3-0.8 1.4-1.9 10.3-2.4 14.4-0.5 4.2 0 8.1-1.7 9.1s-18.7 0.9-19.9 0.9c-1.2 0-6.9-1.8-5.8-3.2 1.2-1.5 2.7-1.8 5.2-3.7s6.8-5 6.8-5zm-39.6-20 13.2-0.5c0.1 2.5 0.9 5-0.2 7.2l-12.7 0.4c-0.2-1.9-0.6-3.4-0.3-7.1zm3.6 30.1s-1.7-4.6-1.2-7.8c0.7-4.4 5.4-5.2 8.6-5.2s4.6 3.7 4.9 5c0.3 1.4 0.6 4.6 0.6 4.6s-1.7-4.6-3.8-5.4c-2.4-0.9-5.6-0.2-7.4 1.6-1.8 1.8-1.8 7.3-1.8 7.3zm-1.2 10.8s-2.6 2.8-2.9 6.1c-0.3 3.2-1 7.3 1.7 10.9 2.7 3.6 6.8 9.7 10.5 6.9s10.9-10.4 11.7-11.7c0.8-1.4 0.6-6.9 0.1-8.9s-1.6-4.2-1.6-4.2 0.7 3.1-1.8 5.3-15.1 5.3-17.4 3.6c-2.3-1.8-0.3-8-0.3-8z"/>
    <path  fill="#87cdde" d="m302.6 349.6 25.9-7.3 2.2 1 6.3-1.2-29.3 21.5z"/>
    <path  fill="#afdde9" d="m302.6 349.6s4 28.6 2.9 37.1c-1.7 13.9-1.2 34.9 2 49.1l7.3-2.4-6.1-83.7z"/>
    <path  fill="#d5f6ff" d="m308.7 349.6 4.9 1.5c4.3 29 15.5 58.6 6.1 86.4l-4.9-4.1z"/>
    <path id="path3109" fill="#d7eef4" d="m307.4 435.7 7.3-2.4 4.9 4.1z"/>
    <path  fill="#37abc8" d="m313.6 351 23.4-9c0.6 20.6 7.5 40.6 9.6 58.7 0.9 7.4 0.4 14.3-2.5 20.9l-24.4 15.9s2.2-15.6 2.3-23.4c0.2-13.9-8.4-63-8.4-63z"/>
    <path  fill="url(#linearGradient4283)" d="m327.6 305.9-2.8 9.3-10.4 1.4-1.2-5.4 0.8-2.8c-0.4 0-0.9 0.1-1.3 0.1l-1.7 1-1.5 7.3s-26 5.8-28.1 5.8c-1 0-5.7-1.6-7.1-1.2 2.2 1.5 4.8 2.5 7.6 2 7.2-1.1 48.2-7.4 51.3-7.4 0.5 0 0.9-0.1 1.5-0.4-2.1-0.4-4.7-1-5.2-1.5-0.9-0.9-1.9-8.2-1.9-8.2z"/>
    <path  fill="#216778" d="m319.7 354.2c-0.6-0.8-8.1-36.8-7.6-40.8 0.7-5.5 1.5-7 4.1-7.3 1-0.1 2.8 1.9 2.8 1.9-2.2 0.3-4 0.3-4.9 2.6-2.9 7.6 8.3 41.8 8.3 42.8-0.1 2.1-1.2 2.9-2.8 0.9z"/>
    <path  fill="#216778" d="m322.3 317.2c3.4 11 7.4 22 10 33 0.5 2.1-2.5 3.3-2.8 1.2-1.6-11.3-5.8-22.7-9.1-34z"/>
    <path  fill="#216778" d="m307.7 348.2s-1.1-26.9 2.3-38.5c1.1-3.7 5.1-3 5.1-3l0.2 1.6s-3.3-0.1-3.9 2.8c-2.4 11.9-1.9 36.7-1.9 36.7z"/>
    <path  fill="#164450" d="m317.9 317.8 4.5 26.2-2.3 0.6-3.6-26.6z"/>
    <path  fill="#8a0" d="m346.9 351 0.7 2 12.7-2-37.8 28.3-6.3-19z"/>
    <path  fill="#cdde87" d="m316.1 360.3 9.5 1 5.9 55.7-14.2 7.6c2.2-18.4 1.1-41.3-1.2-64.2z"/>
    <path  fill="#cdde87" d="m332 360.1 28.3-9s0.4 19.3 2 28.8c1.7 10.2 7.8 28.8 8.1 30 0.2 1.2-0.7 2.9-2 3.4-1.2 0.5-22.9 15.4-22.9 15.4-9.4-19-13.1-42.4-13.4-68.6z"/>
    <path  fill="#efa" d="m325.7 361.3 6.3-1.2s5.9 44.2 7.1 48.6 6.3 20 6.3 20l-13.9-11.7z"/>
    <path  fill="#f6ffd5" d="m317.4 424.5 14.2-7.6 13.9 11.7z"/>
    <path  fill="#89a02c" d="m331.6 316.1 8.2 37.1-2.5 0.8-7.8-37.6z"/>
    <path  fill="#bcd35f" d="m328.1 306.3c-2.6 19.1 15.1 54.7 15.1 55.7-0.2 3.4-1.3 2.8-2.8 0.7-2.3-3.3-14.4-33.5-15.1-55.8-0.1-2.2 4.3-4.1 4.3-4.1s-1.3 1.9-1.6 3.5z"/>
    <path  fill="#bcd35f" d="m334.6 315.6c7.4 14.4 17 27.9 19.2 42.6 0.2 1.1-1.8 4.6-2.6 0.9-3.2-14.7-11.3-28.6-18.6-43.2z"/>
    <path  fill="#bcd35f" d="m324.5 307.2c-0.3 19.2-0.8 34.7-1.8 51.2l2-0.6c-0.3-16.1 3-34.5 2.5-52.5 0 0-2.7-0.4-2.7 2z"/>
    <path  fill="url(#linearGradient4208)" d="m150.3 241-0.1 0-5.7 13.1c0.8 2.6 3.9-2.7 7.1 1 3.3 3.9 3 19 3 19l10.5-5.5s-1.2-11.5-4.2-16.2c-2.6-4.3-11.3-9.9-11.3-9.9s0.4-0.8 0.7-1.4z"/>
    <path fill="url(#linearGradient4249)" d="m228.2 285.7c-0.4 3.3-1.3 8.1-1.7 8.7-1 1.6-3.5 1.3-7.5-0.7l2.5 2.8c-4.1 2.3-8.6 1.6-12.4 0.6l5.9 1.9-4.5 7.5s3.3 8 3.8 10 1 16.9 1.5 25.6c0.3 4.7 8.3 10.1 8.8 11.1s8.9 8.4 12 13.5c13.4 21.8 24.5 62.7 28 71.4 5.8-3.6 12.2-8.7 12.2-8.7s-6.4-9.9-8.4-14.8c-1.9-4.9-12.5-31.4-17.5-38.8-5.1-7.4-27.1-29.2-29.4-30.4-2.3-1.2-4.5-7.6-4.5-7.6s3.1-18.9 4.5-21.6c1.4-2.7 5.1-14.6 5.1-14.6l2.5-0.4-1.6-2.3 3.3-4.1s-1-4.1-2.5-9z"/>
    <path  fill="#f5a36c" d="m236.7 269.7c-0.8-0.2-7.8 2.1-7.8 2.1s2.6 0.8 3.5 1.2c0.5 0.2 1.9 2.2 3.1 4.2l2.7-6.1c-0.3-0.5-0.9-1.3-1.4-1.4z"/>
    <path  fill="#ffd5d5" d="m206.9 684.3c-0.2-0.6-2.1-2-1.9 0.1 0.2 2 0.7 4.3 2.2 5.6 0.7 0.6 3.5 3.5 2.6 0.5-0.1-0.3-2.3-3.9-3-6.3z"/>
    <path  fill="#ffd5d5" d="m242.3 655s-9.3 5-7.7 5.7c1.7 0.8 8-3.5 8.6-4.2 0.6-0.8-0.9-1.5-0.9-1.5z"/>
    <path  fill="#f5a36c" d="m199.7 243.9c-1 0.9-0.1 3.5 0.4 4.1 0.5 0.5 2.8 1.3 3.8-0.2 1.1-1.5 1.5-3.1 1.5-3.1s-1.7 2-2.3 2c-0.7 0-1.2-2.3-1.7-2.4-0.5-0.2-1.3-0.7-1.7-0.3z"/>
    <path  transform="translate(11.334 67.532)" fill="url(#linearGradient4514)" d="m341.8 200.8c-1.8 5.4-7.1 15.4-7.1 15.4l1.2-6s2.1-7.5 2.4-10.2c0.2-1.7-0.7-2.3-1.2-0.8-0.7 2.1-4.1 12.9-4.1 12.9l-3.1 10.9-2.8 6.2c-0.3 1.6 1.2 5.4 7.1 0.9 1.9-1.4 3.5-1.9 5.3-2.6l3.8-6.1s6.4-5.6 7.8-7.2c0.9-1.1 1.4-3-0.2-1.4-0.5 0.9-9.7 7.3-9.7 7.3l0.3-1.5s5.3-13 6.3-16.2c2.1-6.8-0.9-2.9-0.9-2.9s-1 2.4-1.6 3.5c-2 4.3-6.3 12.8-6.3 12.8l5.4-16.2c-0.4-4.9-1.9-0.7-2.6 1.2z"/>
  </g>
</svg>   
</div>
</div>
<body>
```