# Увеличение кругов на CSS3

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Почему при добавлении к `.circle` свойства `scale` он перестает выравниваться по центру?

```css
.furniture-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: scale(4);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(110, 100, 204, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 100, 204, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.querySelector('.circle').style.transform='scale(2) translate(-50%, -50%)'">Zoom</button>

<div class="furniture-item active">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/7fhnk7mn/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Трансформации применяются **последовательно** - масштабирование нужно применять **после** сдвига.

`transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2);`

```css
.furniture-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: scale(4);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(110, 100, 204, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 100, 204, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.querySelector('.circle').style.transform='translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2)'">Zoom</button>

<div class="furniture-item active">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Вы смещаете точку отсчета к центру фигуры за счет `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`. Параметры здесь нужно корректировать исходя из значения `scale`:

- При `scale(1)` - `-50%`
- При `scale(2)` - `-25%`
- При `scale(4)` - `-12.5%`
- При `scale(N)` - `-50% / N` (формула в общем виде)

Стабильнее будет работать отрицательный `margin`, заданный в половину ширины и высоты блока (в пикселях):

```css
.furniture-item {
  background-color: rgba(110, 100, 204, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: scale(4);
  width: 100px;
}

.circle {
  background-color: rgba(0, 100, 204, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -12.5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: scale(2);
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="furniture-item active">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gambala/yro5t08f/).

Comment: скажите по какой формуле считается значение смещение внутреннего круга, допусти scale большого 1.7, маленького 6. Есть какая то формула

Comment: Для `translate` формула: `-50% / scale`. При `1.7` это будет `-50% / 1.7 = -29.41%`, для `6` будет `-50% / 6 = -8.33%`. Если же задавать отрицательный `margin` - то от `scale` он не зависит, для него просто поделите ширину и высоту блока пополам. Например, при `width: 30px; height: 20px;` нужно будет задать `margin: -10px -15px;` и можно использовать любой `scale`..

Comment: да, вариант с margin куда удобнее и проще для понимания

Answer (score 2):

Возвращать надо на 50% от старого размера, т.е. на 25% от увеличенного:

```css
.furniture-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: scale(4);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(110, 100, 204, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: scale(2) translate(-25%, -25%);
  transform-origin: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 100, 204, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="furniture-item active">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Решение SVG

При применении команды **scale(n)** в `SVG` происходит всё тоже самое, как и в CSS - чем больше увеличение, тем больше объект сдвигается от начального положения.

```
<circle cx="40px" cy="40px" r="20px" transform="scale(2)" fill="greenyellow" stroke="none" opacity="0.9" />
```

Как известно начало координат у `svg` находится в левом, верхнем углу.
При cx="40" cy="40" центр окружности будет расположен правее на 40px и ниже на 40px от левого угла (0,0) вьюпорта svg. При применении **`scale(2)`** эти цифры умножаются на два. Только из-за этого круг сместится правее и ниже.
 Новые координаты центра окружности будут cx="80" и cy="80".
 Для наглядности смотрите анимацию процесса.
 Здесь к розовому кругу последовательно применяется увеличение в 1-2-4 раза и обратно 4-2-1

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The increase of the circle when you hover</title>
   </head>
 <body>
 <svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
   width="300px" height="300px">
    
          <text x="70" y="15">mouseover on pink circle</text>
  <circle cx="40px" cy="40px" r="20px" transform="scale(2)" fill="greenyellow" stroke="none" opacity="0.9" /> 
  
  <circle cx="40px" cy="40px" r="20px" transform="scale(4)" fill="dodgerblue" stroke="none" opacity="0.9" />
  <text x="132" y="162">Scale(4)</text>
  <text x="52" y="82">Scale(2)</text>
  <circle id="circle1" cx="40px" cy="40px" r="20px" fill="violet" stroke="none" opacity="0.5">
  <animateTransform id="an1" fill="freeze" attributeName="transform" type="scale" dur="4s"  begin="circle1.mouseover" values="1;2;4" restart="whenNotActive"/>
  <animateTransform id="an2" fill="freeze" attributeName="transform" begin="an1.end" type="scale" dur="1s"  begin="circle1.mouseover"           values="4;4" restart="whenNotActive"/> 
  <animateTransform id="an3" fill="freeze" attributeName="transform" begin="an2.end" type="scale" dur="2s"    begin="circle1.mouseover"           values="4;2;1" restart="whenNotActive"/>
  
  </circle>

 </svg>
 
 </body>
```

**Вариант 1:**

Как с этим бороться,- есть несколько вариантов:
Допустим необходимо увеличить объект максимум в 4 раза.
Считаем координаты центра: 40*4= 160px; 
И сразу располагаем центр окружности с этими координатами: cx="160" cx="160" Теперь у нас есть уверенность, что круг не выйдет при увеличении за пределы канвы SVG.  см. пример ниже.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The increase of the circle when you hover</title>
   </head>
 <body>
 <svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
   width="300px" height="300px">
    <text x="70" y="15">mouseover on greenyellow circle</text>
  
 <! --the maximum limit of the increase of circle - dotted-->
  <circle  cx="160px" cy="160px" r="81px" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke="gray" stroke-dasharray="15 10" opacity="0.9" />    
  
  <circle cx="160px" cy="160px" r="20px"  fill="dodgerblue" stroke="none" opacity="0.9" > 
  <animate attributeName="r" id="an1" fill="freeze"  begin="c1.mouseover"  dur="4s"   values="20;80;20;80" restart="whenNotActive"/> 
  </circle>
   <circle id="c1" cx="160px" cy="160px" r="20px" fill="greenyellow" stroke="none" opacity="0.9" /> 
  
 </svg>
 
 </body>
```

Следующий пример немного посложнее, с двумя кругами, попутно можно посмотреть, как взаимодействуют между собой две анимации.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The increase of the circle when you hover</title>
   </head>
 <body>
 <svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
   width="300px" height="300px">

   <text x="70" y="15">mouseover on greenyellow circle</text>
   
  <! --the maximum limit of the increase of circle - dotted-->
  <circle  cx="160px" cy="160px" r="80px" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-dasharray="15 10" opacity="0.9" />  

  <circle cx="160px" cy="160px" r="20px"  fill="dodgerblue" stroke="none" opacity="0.9" > 
  <animate id="an1" attributeName="r"  fill="freeze"  begin="c1.mouseover;an2.end+0.2s"  dur="4s"   values="20;80;20" restart="whenNotActive"/> 
  </circle>

  <circle cx="160px" cy="160px" r="20px"  fill="crimson" stroke="none" opacity="0.9" > 
  <animate id="an2" attributeName="r"  fill="remove"  begin="an1.end"  dur="4s"   values="20;80;20;80" restart="whenNotActive"/> 
  </circle>
  
  <circle id="c1" cx="160px" cy="160px" r="20px" fill="greenyellow" stroke="none" opacity="0.9" /> 
  
 </svg>
 
 </body>
```

**Вариант 2**
Если вам нужно разместить окружность в углу канвы, но вы не хотите, чтобы она при увеличении уходила за границы канвы или убегала к центру по диагонали, делайте координаты центра окружности равными радиусу окружности.

```
<circle cx="20px" cy="20px" r="20px" />
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>An expanding circle in the corner</title>
   </head>
 <body>
 <svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
   width="300px" height="300px">
    <text x="20" y="185">mouseover on greenyellow circle</text>
  
 <! --the maximum limit of the increase of circle - dotted-->
  <circle  cx="80px" cy="80px" r="82px" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke="gray" stroke-dasharray="15 10" opacity="0.9" />  
  
  <circle cx="20px" cy="20px" r="20px"  fill="dodgerblue" stroke="none" opacity="0.9" > 
  <animateTransform id="an1" fill="freeze" attributeName="transform" type="scale" dur="4s"  begin="c1.mouseover" values="1;2;4" restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </circle>
   <circle id="c1" cx="20px" cy="20px" r="20px" fill="greenyellow" stroke="none" opacity="0.9" /> 
  
 </svg>
 
 </body>
```

Есть еще несколько способов для удержания, центрирования объекта при масштабировании. В ответах других участников уже всё хорошо объяснено. Спасибо за это всем участвующим.

Comment: проблема svg заключается в том что я не могу увеличить круг больше области svg, В html я могу взять блок 16px, разместить в нем круг абсолютно, и трансформировать его до каких угодно размеров. Есть в svg нечто похожее?

Comment: @ruslik попробуйте вопрос сформулировать по другому, ничего не понял, область svg бесконечна, как наша вселенная :)

Comment: @ruslik http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566192/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-svg-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-fullpage/648773#648773  вот может быть это ответит на ваш вопрос, там происходит масштабирование SVG в зависимости от размеров экрана