# Как заставить масштабироваться квадраты-svg?

Tags: css3, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу понять как масштабируется svg. Устанавливается viewbox через медиазапросы на каждое разрешение или влияют через флексбоксы(возможен ли вообще такой вариант). Каким бы путем вы пошли верстая такую секцию? Сначала делал так:

```
    <body>
```

```
    <rect class="works" width="100" height="100" fill="purple" stroke="white"/>

    <rect class="works" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="white"/>

    <rect class="works" width="100" height="100" fill="purple" stroke="white"/>

    <rect class="works" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="white"/>

    <rect class="works" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="white"/>

    <line x1="0" y1="-150" x2="0" y2="0" stroke="white"/>
</svg>

</header>
```

`

```
body {
 background-color: black;
}

svg :first-of-type {
    transform:  translateX(300px) translateY(100px) rotate(45deg);}
svg :nth-of-type(2) {
            transform: translateX(442px) translateY(100px) rotate(45deg);}
svg :nth-of-type(3) {
            transform: translateX(442px) translateY(241px) rotate(45deg);}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amd15qLa/9/

Затем решил все сделать в Inkscape. (код в редакторе получился какой-то длинный и грязный). И вообще изображение в редакторе набросал, а иконки социальные не смог перевести в вектор. И текст в эти квадраты потом подгонять что ли для адаптивности? Помогите, набросать алгоритм действий, пожалуйста. В какую сторону смотреть..

Comment: Здравствуйте! Отлучался по некоторым обстоятельствам и вот щас сел разбираться с этим. Спасибо огромное, что нашли время на такое подробное и доходчивое разъяснение!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать нечто более сложное, чем добавление иконок svg из спрайта в HTML, то необходимо будет освоить некоторые азы `SVG`.
 Путь не легкий, но интересный. 
Все вопросы, которые вы задаёте в том или ином виде уже встречались.  При желании для изучения теории, сделайте выборку по тегу `svg`(пункт меню "Метки") 
Вот некоторые ответы:

**Масштабирование**

- [Как взаимодействуют между собой viewport и viewBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615562/28748)
- [масштабирование SVG элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620606/28748)
- [Проблема с svg и плагином fullpage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648773/28748)

**Оптимизация SVG изображения, в том числе после рисования в векторных редакторах:**

- [Как выбирать и дорабатывать изображения SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657213/28748)
- [Почему появляется смещение по y](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619902/28748)
- [Почему svg отображается в маленьком размере?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653295/28748)

**Добавление социальных иконок**

[Как добавить в footer социальные иконки bootstrap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651221/28748)

### Примеры:

Ваш пример можно доработать на чистом SVG, а потом уже добавить одним блоком в HTML. 
Исходя из ваших размеров блока квадратов устанавливаем viewport и viewBox: `500x500`

```html
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  </head>

  <body>

 <svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="500px" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="border:1px solid red;" >
  <g   stroke="white" >
  <rect class="works" x="50" y="200" width="100" height="100" fill="purple" />

  <rect class="works" x="150" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />

  <rect class="works" x="250" y="200"  width="100" height="100" fill="purple" />
  
  <rect class="works"  x="250" y="300"  width="100" height="100" fill="blue"  /> 
  

  <rect class="works" x="350" y="200" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
  
  <line x1="50" y1="200" x2="50" y2="50" stroke-width="1" />
  <line x1="450" y1="300" x2="600" y2="300" stroke-width="1" />
  <line x1="250" y1="400" x2="250" y2="500" stroke-width="1" />
 </g>
 </svg>
 


  </body>
```

Код оборачиваем групповым тегом `<g>... </g>`, чтобы в последствии применить к нему трансформации, как к единому целому элементу и не мучиться с вычислением координат для каждого квадрата.

Поворачиваем группу на 45 градусов, вокруг центра вращения 250х250px

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  </head>
<style>
  body {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTvBfG3RU9FtABFmZQeqeNjnb0twz5xSvGIKFcgsAGew35Rj9NFw') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  </style>
  <body>

 <svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="500px" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500"  >
  <g transform="rotate(45 250 250)" opacity="0.5" stroke="white" >
  <rect class="works" x="50" y="200" width="100" height="100" fill="purple" />

  <rect class="works" x="150" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />

  <rect class="works" x="250" y="200"  width="100" height="100" fill="purple" />
  
  <rect class="works"  x="250" y="300"  width="100" height="100" fill="blue"  /> 
  

  <rect class="works" x="350" y="200" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
  
  <line x1="50" y1="200" x2="50" y2="50" stroke-width="1" />
  <line x1="450" y1="300" x2="600" y2="300" stroke-width="1" />
  <line x1="250" y1="400" x2="250" y2="500" stroke-width="1" />
 </g>
 </svg>
 


  </body>
```

**Добавление текста в блок SVG**

Для добавления применяются теги `<text> ... </text>` с необходимыми атрибутами для стилизации. Координаты начала текста определяются в нашем примере x="-140" y="250" 
Текст "Lorem" поворачиваем предварительно на -45 градусов, для того чтобы при повороте группы квадратов на +45 текст был горизонтален.

```
<text x="-140" y="250" stroke="white" font-size="24" transform="rotate(-45)" >Lorem</text>
```

```html
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  </head>
<style>
  body {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTvBfG3RU9FtABFmZQeqeNjnb0twz5xSvGIKFcgsAGew35Rj9NFw') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  </style>
  <body>

 <svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="500px" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500"  >
  <g transform="rotate(45 250 250)" opacity="0.5" stroke="white" >
  <rect class="works" x="50" y="200" width="100" height="100" fill="purple" />

  <rect class="works" x="150" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />

  <rect class="works" x="250" y="200"  width="100" height="100" fill="purple" />
  
  <rect class="works"  x="250" y="300"  width="100" height="100" fill="blue"  /> 
  
  <rect class="works" x="350" y="200" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
  
  <line x1="50" y1="200" x2="50" y2="50" stroke-width="1" />
  <line x1="450" y1="300" x2="600" y2="300" stroke-width="1" />
  <line x1="250" y1="400" x2="250" y2="500" stroke-width="1" />  
  
  <text x="-140" y="250" stroke="white" font-size="24" transform="rotate(-45)" >Lorem</text>
        <text x="0" y="250" stroke="white" fill="white" font-family="Verdana" font-size="32" transform="rotate(-90) translate(-455 -35)" >BrandaLOKA.</text>
 </g>
 </svg>
 


  </body>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. После долгой разлуки, снова вернулся к svg...Скажите, пожалуйста, выше код вы сами от руки писали или в редакторе рисовали??

Comment: @Этот конкретный код конечно от руки писал в текстовом редакторе. Но это примитив, основы svg - линии, квадраты,  круги. Для рисования более сложных фигур с криволинейными очертаниями, конечно нужен векторный редактор.  Советую начать изучение с ручного рисования.

Comment: А скажите, как вы высчитывали  координаты этого "примитива"?Я помню, я очень много времени потратил подгоняя пиксели линий, квадратов(чтобы рядышком их разложить), углы наклона.В конце концов наплевал на этот svg( Это вообще жесть. Так должно быть? Или есть какой-то алгоритм быстрого подгона? Поделитесь, плиз

Comment: @Safbek Всё дело в опыте, а он без практики не приходит. Вы мучились подбирая координаты наклонных линий, а это действительно непросто. Проще было делать горизонтальные фигуры, а потом их обернуть групповым тегом `<g>` и повернуть вместе. Затем можно подгонять положение фигур по "x" и  "y"  командой `transform="translate(x y)"` С появлением смартфонов,- за svg  будущее векторной графики.  Посмотрите вот этот пост  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/753664/28748 посмотрите примеры анимации SVG, которые просто невозможно сделать на CSS

Comment: Спасибо, что находите время на ответы, добрый человек)Все немного проясняется, но думаю, что еще не раз обращусь за помощью. А пока хорошенько поковыряюсь в svg. Еще раз спасибо!